# Running Commands in Batch FIle

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, command-prompt

I am trying to create a batch file to run start some micro services and database

```
   1 FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :1000') DO @ECHO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P
   2 FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :1001') DO @ECHO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P
   3 FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :5432') DO @ECHO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P
   4 start cd "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\" & pg_ctl.exe -D "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data" start 
    @REM to start service
   5 start javaw -jar -Dserver.port=1000 text-annotation-tool-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Line 1 to 3 and Line 5 execute correctly when executed by commenting line 4.

Line 4 is to start a Postgres server in a new prompt (beacuse of the Dir change).  I think the problem is with the way I have used quotes. The 'start' at the beginning and ending of line 4 serve different purpose.

Also, if I execute line 4 in different prompt, How do I close the prompt after execution (nohup equivalent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors: You can't "pass" `cd` to the start command. And `start` has the quirk to interpret the first quoted parameter as the new window's title. So `start "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\" ...` wouldn't work, you need to supply a dummy window title. The `&` also seems wrong

So you need:

```
start "Postgres Server" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\pg_ctl.exe" -D "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data" start
```

As the full path to `pg_ctl.exe` is supplied, there is no need for a `cd`. 
But if you want to define the default directory for the new process, you have to use the `/D` parameter:

```
start "Postgres Server" /D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin" pg_ctl.exe -D "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data" start
```

---

Unrelated, but: putting the Postgres data directory into `c:\Program Files\` is a very bad idea. That directory has special permissions for a purpose. You should use `%ProgramData%` or `%AppData%` instead

Comment: Yes, you are right about the 'data' directory. This one was a default setup of postgres.  Is there a nohup equivalent for that new process. I mean, the command is executed in the "Postgres Server" process. can we suppress this prompt

Comment: @Betafish: not with plain batch scripting. I did something like that with a `.vbs` script.

Comment: Can I use a similar command to first stop and then start the postgres server `start "Postgres Server" /D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin" pg_ctl.exe -D "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data" stop`  `"Postgres Server" /D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin" pg_ctl.exe -D "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data" start`

Comment: I wouldn't run `pg_ctl ... stop` using the `start`  command as you want to wait for the outcome of that before you re-start Postgres. So `pg_ctl -D ... stop` then `start "postgres" pg_ctl -D  ... start`